# Is it possible to remove an item type from a lineitem.aggregate when making a different calculation?

Tags: python, django, aggregate, calculated-field

The delivery cost should not include % on booking, but should include % of product price if below the set delivery threshold. Both can be added to an order and at checkout only the product should attract a delivery cost, as the booking relates to buying experiences. I am unable to figure this out, so if anyone can help me I would be most grateful. Below is my model code for checkout, which includes the Order Model where the delivery is being calculated, and Order Line Item Model from where the order total is being calculated using line item aggregate.

```
    def update_total(self):
        """
        Updates grand total each time a line item is added,
        takes into account delivery costs
        """
        self.order_total = self.lineitems.aggregate(
            Sum('lineitem_total'))['lineitem_total__sum'] or 0
        if self.order_total < settings.FREE_DELIVERY_THRESHOLD:
            self.delivery_cost = self.order_total * \
                settings.STANDARD_DELIVERY_PERCENTAGE / 100
        else:
            self.delivery_cost = 0
        self.grand_total = self.order_total + self.delivery_cost
        self.save()


class OrderLineItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, null=False, blank=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lineitems')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, blank=True,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    experience = models.ForeignKey(Experiences, null=True, blank=True,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    lineitem_total = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False, editable=False
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False,)

    def get_price(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.product and self.experience:
            return self.product.price + self.experience.price
        elif self.product:
            return self.product.price
        elif self.experience:
            return self.experience.price

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Overrides the original save method to set the lineitem total
        and updates the order total
        """

        self.price = self.get_price()
        self.lineitem_total = int(self.price) * self.quantity

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```